# kamailio sip server with tls

Tags: sip, sip-server, kamailio

i am trying to configure kamailio on my locak systen .
i have installed kamailio on my linux i getting call properly. but when i try to connect by tls getting following errors in log file.

```
ct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: rtpproxy [rtpproxy.c:1592]: rtpp_test(): rtp proxy <udp:127.0.0.1:7722> found, support for it enabled
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:275]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: tls_method=9
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:287]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: certificate='/etc/kamailio/server.crt'
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:294]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: ca_list='/etc/kamailio/servercakey.pem'
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:301]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: crl='(null)'
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:305]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: require_certificate=0
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:312]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: cipher_list='(null)'
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:319]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: private_key='/etc/kamailio/server.key'
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:323]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: verify_certificate=0
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: INFO: tls [tls_domain.c:326]: fill_missing(): TLSs<default>: verify_depth=9
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: ERROR: tls [tls_domain.c:535]: load_ca_list(): TLSs<default>: Unable to load CA list '/etc/kamailio/servercakey.pem'
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: ERROR: <core> [sr_module.c:927]: init_mod_child(): init_mod_child(): Error while initializing module tls (/usr/lib64/kamailio/modules/tls.so)
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: ERROR: <core> [sr_module.c:927]: init_mod_child(): init_mod_child(): Error while initializing module tls (/usr/lib64/kamailio/modules/tls.so)
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: ERROR: <core> [main.c:1575]: main_loop(): ERROR: main: error in init_child(PROC_INT) -- exiting
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: ERROR: ctl [ctl.c:379]: mod_destroy(): ERROR: ctl: could not delete unix socket /tmp/kamailio_ctl: Operation not permitted (1)
```

i tried to generate new certificate , done already 3 times but still getting some error.
i need experts help. please guide me .

Comment: Can you please add the errors that you are getting when you are generating the local server Cert? Go for a self signed certificate and provide the public cert to the sipp [or any other tool] that you are using to connect? This clearly shows the certs missing in the path and that could mean the file is not a valid cert. Cross check with Openssl commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you provide a path to a Certificate Authority (CA) file that doesn't exist or has broken content:

```
Oct 21 12:12:48 localhost /usr/sbin/kamailio[3612]: ERROR: tls [tls_domain.c:535]: load_ca_list(): TLSs<default>: Unable to load CA list '/etc/kamailio/servercakey.pem'
```

Either put the right path or file content if you used custom CA or just comment ca_list parameter if you want to work with default operating system (openssl lib) CA list.